# why my html file doesnt fit different android screen sizes?

Tags: java, android, html, android-webview

I have following code,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView mWebView = null;
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/FE/index.html");
}
```

but, the html page doesnt scale itself according to the screen size.

Comment: Can you please show us your layout xml?

Comment: Please post your layout code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these Lines for your `webview`:

```
     mWebView.setInitialScale(1);
     mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
     mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
     mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
```

and dont hard-code `WebView` layout parameters in `layout.xml` file. Use `fill_parent` for `layout_width` and `layout_height` instead.

Comment: The method setSupportMultipleWindows(true) is undefined for the type WebView

Comment: import the following: import android.webkit.WebSettings.ZoomDensity;

Comment: sorry. replace that line with mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true); I forgot to add getSettings()... edited my answer... check now...

Comment: without mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true); the index.html fit the screen but now it failed due to invalid APK file.

Comment: I think there is no need of that setSupportMultipleWindows line as per your requirement....remove that line and once clean and build the project. That invalid apk file error will be resolved...

Comment: and now WHAT THE ... is "installation failed due to invalid URI"

Comment: i dont know what exactly you are doing... Just UNDO where you got worked it

Comment: THANKS a lot mate. you are a champ. one more question...just the index file fits the screen but not the rest of the pages i goto via index page. would be great if you could point me into right direction. thanks again mate

Comment: i accepted your answer but the website doesnt allow me to vote up

Comment: i goto other pages by clicking the buttons on the main html file. and the text appears on 1/3 of the screen. this width problem isnt in CSS i must add

Comment: adding on to that, buttons and labels etc do scale themselves

Answer (score 2):

**XML code ...**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java Code ...**

```
WebView mWebView = null;

mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

**Html Code ....** (index.html) put this in assets folder

```
<HEAD>
    <TITLE> HTML PAGE </TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <b> Hello World ...! </b>
</BODY>
```

It works **perfectly** for me ...

Comment: i have a HTML file in assert filder which has buttons and stuff. all i need is to display a HTML file which is screen size independent.